# Clearing Saved Password from Chrome after Authenticating from External Browser with Xamarin.Auth

Tags: google-chrome, xamarin.forms, oauth-2.0, xamarin.auth

We are facing the problem that once we make a successful OAuth2 Authentication using Google Chrome, the web browser saves the details and so the next time we try to authenticate, Chrome skips over to the "Accept/Cancel" privileges. This is a security risk and an annoyance as well. Is there any way around this?